Movie about a cheating husband whose mistress tries to kill his wife
This is a drama movie. It's about a husband cheating on his wife and he has a mistress. The mistress finds out where he lives and stalks the wife. She goes into her house when her husband leaves to work. The mistress tried to kill her with the wife's own Steel Comb Hair Pin that is similar to the one that Chinese women use in their hair.

Welcome to Movies & TV SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you watched the movie, and what movies you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

By hair pin do you mean a single hair pin or do you mean a metal hair comb?

It could be Fatal Attraction with Michael Douglas and Glenn Close, released in 1987.

A married man's one-night stand comes back to haunt him when that lover begins to stalk him and his family.


Dan Gallagher is a successful New York lawyer with a beautiful wife named Beth, and 6-year-old daughter named Ellen who spends a weekend with a book editor named Alex Forrest. As far as he is concerned, it's a one-time thing but she has something more in mind, as she amply demonstrates even before the weekend is over. When he makes it clear that there is no future for them, she begins to seek him out, whether constantly calling him at home or work and even visiting him at his apartment, which is up for sale, and meeting Beth. Her obsession knows no bounds and she becomes increasingly violent, putting his life - and that of his family's - in danger.

